# Implement COM interface C++ / VC++ 6.0 / MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl

Entry level programmer here trying to implement a COM interface. I am working on a program that interfaces with the Aloha point of sale system. Aloha uses COM to work with external programs. I am trying to intercept card data from the mag card reader, which is an OPOS reader, not a keyboard wedge. The documentation I have doesn't explain how to implement this particular interface, but it does explain how to implement a similar one. I have tried to follow this example but I am getting no where. Support from Aloha is non-existent, their documentation is poor, outdated and sometimes just wrong, even though I have paid for a license.

I tried to make a simple app just to test this functionality. Here is what I did:

1) create a new project in vc++ 6.0 using ATL COM app wizard
2) server type dll
3) insert new atl object -> simple object
4) right click on my new class and choose implement interface
5) browse for type library, chose Iber.tlb (Aloha's tlb)
6) chose the interface I want to implement

That made a .h, .cpp and .rgs file.

The .h file has:

```
public:
// IInterceptMagcard
    STDMETHOD(InterceptMagcard)(BSTR bstrAccountNumber, BSTR bstrCustomerName, BSTR bstrExpirationDate, BSTR bstrTrack1Info, BSTR bstrTrack2Info, BSTR bstrTrack3Info, BSTR bstrRawMagcardData, LONG * bWasDataHandled)
    {
        if (bWasDataHandled == NULL)
            return E_POINTER;

        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }
```

Is that where I implement my code? I put some test code in there to write out to a txt file just to test it. I then used:

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AlohaMag, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                                IID_IAlohaMag, (void **) &g_pIInterceptMagcard);
```

where g_pIInterceptMagcard is a pointer to my interface class created with the wizard above.

When I try to register I get the following HRESULT: 0x80040112
That is "class not licensed for use."

Does that mean my program didn't make the necessary registry entries?

Comment: This doesn't explain your problem but: the g_pIInterceptMagcard variable should not be a pointer to your interface class since [CoCreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615(v=VS.85).aspx) will overwrite it with a pointer to the class implementing CLSID_AlohaMag.

Comment: @Frank: Not quite sure what you mean. On return, g_pIInterceptMagcard will point to the IAlohaMag interface of an AlohaMag object. I don't think your term "interface class" is clear because the separation of interface from implementation is crucial in COM. (There's no such thing as an "interface class".) And the returned pointer points to an object, not to a class. (There's no such thing as a pointer to a class in COM or C++.)

Comment: @ciaran: the OP says "where g_pIInterceptMagcard is a pointer to my interface class created with the wizard above".  I took that to mean something like `g_pIInterceptMagcard  = new MyInterceptMagcard()` was executed before the CoCreateInstance call.  What I was trying to point out was that any attempt to assign g_pIInterceptMagcard  before calling CoCreateInstance is wasted effort because CoCreateInstance overwrites the contents of the last parameter (i.e., g_pIInterceptMagcard ) with a pointer to the interface requested.

Comment: @Frank: Ah yes, I didn't spot that it was Bob's term, not yours. Sorry.

Comment: @Bob To be more explicit, if you set `g_pIInterceptMagcard` to NULL you should find that CoCreateInstance _still_ returns the error.  Your test case failure probably has nothing to do with your implementation of IInterceptMagcard you are just having trouble creaing an instance of the CLSID_AlohaMag class.

Comment: thanks, I am new to this so my terminolgy was a bit off.  g_pIInterceptMagcard is declared as an AlohaMag pointer and is being passed into CoCreateInstance and on return should point to my new AlohaMag coclass in memory right? This interface is a call-back though and  g_pIInterceptMagcard has no methods I need to call directly. It has one method that is called when a certain event happens in Aloha. The prototype of this function is defined in AlohaMag.h and I implement the function in another class. Is this on the right track?

Comment: You're on the right track - yes, you should implement your callback method in the code sample you posted. You need a pointer to the IConnectionPoint interface on the object you want to receive events from (called the event source), and a pointer to the IAlohaMag interface on an object of your own class (the event sink). Then pass your IAlohaMag interface to IConnectionPoint::Advise.

Comment: Back to your error message, though... When you call CoCreateInstance in the code you posted, are you trying to create your own object (the event sink) or the Aloha object (the source)? Is CLSID_AlohaMag your class or Aloha's? There might be some other documented technique for getting a pointer to the Aloha object.

Comment: I am trying to create the sink yes. CLSID_AlohaMag is my class but it is made via VC++ wizards. I insert a new ATL simple object, then in class view right click on the new class and click implement interface. I choose the tlb file that came with my sdk, choose the interface from that tlb that I want to implement. This wizard makes AlohaMag.h, .cpp, and .rgs file. CLSID_AlohaMag is defined in ProjectName_i.c which is generated at compile time. This CLSID looks like it comes from the file ProjectName.idl, which I assume comes from the tlb file I chose when I implemented the interface.

Comment: Should the CLSID of the coclass in my code be the same as the UUID of the same class in the IDL code provided by the documentation? Because it is not. Also I think I should be naming my coclass exactly the same name as the IDL in the documentation? Perhaps instead of using the wizards and using the tlb file in the sdk I should compile the IDL from the documentation using MIDL then implement my interface from the resulting tlb file? Or can I then just use the .h file generated from MIDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means there is a license you have to install before their custom class factory will create an instance of the class.  Did you try running your program on a fully working POS system with the magnetic card swipe licensed for use?  Maybe there is some other license that you need to do this type of thing?

If it was a problem of the class not being registered, the result would be "class not registered".  It sounds like you've done the necessary steps via the wizard to implement the interface and have it generate the correct registry entries.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not very familiar with licenced controls, but you might need to replace CoCreateInstance with explicit calls to CoGetClassObject(IClassFactory2) and IClassFactory2::CreateInstanceLic.

Comment: Generally, you don't need those.  COM wouldn't work very well if every object required some additional documentation describing how to make an instance of the object.  The class factory is created via the object's definition, and that is usually where there is license enforcement.

Comment: CoCreateInstance is a wrapper function that calls CoGetClassObject, IClassFactory::CreateInstance, and IUnknown::QueryInterface on your behalf. But IClassFactory doesn't support licensing - for that you need IClassFactory2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690543%28v=VS.85%29.aspx. But to add to the mix, it's possible that the author of Aloha uses his own custom licensing scheme, unrelated to the standard ActiveX licensing.

Comment: when you guys say licensing, is that in the context of COM or do you mean licensing like I need a license to run Windows? If it is the latter, does that mean the POS system I am testing on must have a license from Aloha?

Comment: @Bob: It looks like whoever made the component you're trying to invoke requires a license for it.  Some companies create their components in a way that prevents creation unless a license is available.

Comment: ok, we bought a license to go ahead and develop on, but I did not get any sort of license file with my SDK. Should I have? I will put a support ticket in but they are so slow and I needed this done like last week.

Comment: yes this was a license issue. My documentation was outdated. I had to use IClassFactory2 and provide a license string in order to use that class.

Comment: 10+ years of COM sometimes comes in handy. ;)  Congrats on getting it working.